# Name for the tree formed after collapsing cycles

Tags: graphs, automata, terminology

What do you call a structure which becomes a tree after collapsing cycles (so the new vertices are the old faces)?
For instance, the digraph (given by an NFA; ignore edge labels please) below becomes a tree
$\{a,b,c,d\}$ with edges $(a,b), (b,c), (b,d)$ via:
\begin{eqnarray*}
a\mapsto&\text{the cycle }&S_0,S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4,S_5,S_6,S_7,S_0
\\
b\mapsto &\text{the cycle }&S_5,S_6,S_7,S_8,S_9,S_{10},S_{11},S_{12},S_5\\
c\mapsto &\text{the cycle }&S_8,S_9,S_8\\
d\mapsto &\text{the cycle }&S_{10},S_{11},S_{12},S_{10}
\end{eqnarray*}
[image: Complexity witness]

Comment: How are you collapsing loops? Every acyclic connected graph is a tree, so if your collapsing doesn't disconnect the graph you'll always end up with a tree.

Comment: I edited your question to replace "loops" with "cycles": a loop is an edge from a vertex to itself. But I can't tell what you're asking, here. First, what do you mean by "collapsing"? Second, what do you mean by "a tree like $\{0,00,000,001\}$? Third, are these graphs or automata? Those aren't the same thing but you talk about them as if they are.

Comment: @DavidRicherby thanks for the point about cycles vs. loops. I've edited to clarify the rest.

Comment: OK but you need to give a definition, not just an example. Actually, I don't understand your example at all. Going round the cycle $S_{10}S_{11}S_{12}S_{10}$ generates the string $110$, not $01$; So where do these strings come from?

Comment: my guess it that these graphs are the [series parallel](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-247X(65)90125-3) graphs, or equivalently graphs that are [K4-minor-free](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_309.html)

Answer (score 1):

For any given *undirected* graph $G$, the *cycle graph* $C(G)$ has vertices which correspond to the chordless cycles of $G$, and two distinct vertices of $C(G)$ are adjacent if and only if the corresponding chordless cycles have at least one edge in common. [1]

Judging from your example, you are interested in a similar notion for a directed graph.

[1] S.V. Gervacio. Cycle graphs. Lect. Notes Math. 1073, 279-293 (1984)

Comment: Thanks, I wonder whether chordless cycles is the right concept though, since the cycle $b$ in my example is apparently not chordless

Comment: A face-defining cycle is chordless.